# Slowing down the running time of the algorithm in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, biginteger

I am trying to implement the Gorner algorithm for calculating the value of a polynomial at a point. I'm running tests to estimate the time complexity of the algorithm. When I use Integer values, the complexity grows as O(n), but as soon as I start using BigInteger, the complexity immediately becomes approximately O(n^2).
Why is this happening?

For Integer:

```
static int hornerAlgorithmInt(int poly[], int n, int x) {
        // Initialize result
        int result = poly[0];

        // Evaluate value of polynomial using Horner's method
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            result = result * x + poly[i];

        return result;
    }

static int getResultInteger(int deg, int x) {
        int result;
        Random rd = new Random(); // creating Random object
        int[] arr = new int[deg];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = rd.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);// storing random integers in an array
        }
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        result = hornerAlgorithmInt(arr, deg, 3);
        long finish = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println((finish - start) / 1000);
        return result;
    }
```

For BigInteger:

```
static BigInteger hornerAlgorithmBig(BigInteger[] poly, int deg, BigInteger x) {
        BigInteger result = poly[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < deg; i++) {
            result = result.multiply(x).add(poly[i]);
        }
        return result;
}

static BigInteger getResultBig(String s, BigInteger x) {
        BigInteger[] polyCoefficient = arrayCreator(s);
        int deg = polyCoefficient.length;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        BigInteger result = hornerAlgorithmBig(polyCoefficient, deg, x);
        long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println((finish - start));
        return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because most operations on `BigInteger` are themselves `O(n)`, assuming the size of the BI instance is itself growing linear to `n`.

For example:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 10;
int c = a + b;
```

The above code is, rather obviously, `O(1)`. However,

```
BigInteger a = ....;
BigInteger b = ....;
BigInteger c = a.add(b);
```

The above code is all on its own `O(n)`! At least, assuming the sizes of a and b are linear to `n`, which they generally are, if BigInteger is required for the algorithm to work.

There's no quick fix for any of this. You need a completely different algorithm, most likely. "Just make BigInt ops be O(1)" is about as sensible as "Just calculate this NP-hard problem with a simple for loop please".